# Using `TStopWatch` without `free`

Tags: delphi, timer, stopwatch

I am using `TStopWatch` for high-precision timekeeping in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

This website: https://www.thoughtco.com/accurately-measure-elapsed-time-1058453 has given the following example:

```
 var
  sw : TStopWatch;
  elapsedMilliseconds : cardinal;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.Create() ;
  try
    sw.Start;
    //TimeOutThisFunction()
    sw.Stop;
    elapsedMilliseconds := sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  finally
    sw.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Apparently, there is a mistake there, since:

- `StopWatch` does not contain `Free`
- Delphi documentation clearly states that:

> `TStopwatch` is not a class but still requires explicit initialization
>   [using `StartNew` or `Create` methods].

This is confusing. I am using `TStopWatch` in a function, and I am not using `free`. This function may be called multiple times during each session (perhaps hundreds of times, depending on the usage). It means multiple instances of `TStopWatch` will be created, without being freed.

Is there a possibility of memory leaks, or other complications? If the answer is yes, what am I supposed to do? Do I have to create only one instance of `TStopWatch` per application? Or should I use other functions? Or something else?

Comment: The important difference between `TStopWatch.Create` and `TStopWatch.StartNew` is that the former creates the stopwatch in a **stopped** state, while the latter creates it in a **started** state. Both have their usage, f.ex. `TStopWatch.Create` in preparation for a repeated and **cumulative** timing of, say, a line in a loop, surrounded by a `start` and a `stop` command. Examples of usage of `StartNew` has been provided by others. It is worthwile to read the [**documentation**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch.Start)

Comment: Your problem is that you are confusing the TStopwatch in the linked article with the one that comes with Delphi. The former is a class, the latter a record with methods. The latter does not need a destructor or Free, and Create does not generate a new stopwatch on each call.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I missed your comment somehow, but it explains a lot. I made the mistake of replacing `TStopWatch.Create` with `TStopWatch.StartNew`. Now, I see I should have used the former. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The linked example is a `TStopWatch` based on a class.

```
unit StopWatch;
interface
uses 
  Windows, SysUtils, DateUtils;

type 
  TStopWatch = class
  ...
```

It was published before Delphi introduced the record based `TStopWatch`.

Since the class variant needs to call `Free` after use, and the record based does not, there is no confusion here.

Just continue using the Delphi record based `TStopWatch` without a need to free it after use.

Usually I use the following pattern:

```
var
  sw : TStopWatch;
begin
  sw := TStopWatch.StartNew;
  ... // Do something
  sw.Stop;
  // Read the timing
  WriteLn(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What do I do with the record variant? Is it okay to use `create` without `free`?

Comment: See my update. You don't need the `Create` at all. It is just a record class function.

Comment: @blackcanopus: The pattern using `SW.StartNew ... SW.ElapsedMilliseconds ... SW.Stop` is the usual one for the `TStopwatch` in `System.Diagnostics`. No need to `Create`, but generally you should call `StartNew`.

Comment: LU RD and @Rudy , there certainly is a good reason for the `Create` also, see my comment to OP.

Comment: @Tom: I always use the StartNew...Stop sequence. Works fine.

Comment: @Rudy, I didn't say it wouldn't. Just continue as it pleases you ;)

Answer (score -1):

This is a class so you need free.
A nice pattern is do measure time just with a memo or console, you run it till you press a key:

```
 sw:= TStopWatch.Create();
  try
    sw.Start;
    //TimeOutThisFunction()
    //sleep(500)
    memo2.setfocus;
    repeat until iskeypressed;
    sw.Stop;
    //elapsedMilliseconds:= sw.getValueStr; 
    writeln('stopwatch '+sw.getValueStr);
  finally
    sw.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: This does not answer the actual question.